# django.contrib.humanize не верно переводит время на русский язык

Tags: python, django, datetime

Баг django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize NaturalTimeFormatter? Неверно/не до конца переводится обозначение времени.

Хочу убедиться, что это действительно баг, либо получить коммент как исправить:

```
import datetime
import random

from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import NaturalTimeFormatter
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse


def random_tm_str():
    choices = tuple(x for x in range(10))
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=random.choice(choices),
                               hours=random.choice(choices),
                               minutes=random.choice(choices))
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return NaturalTimeFormatter.string_for(now - delta)


def index(request):
    txts = '<html>' \
           '<body'+'<br/>'.join(random_tm_str() for x in range(100)) + \
            '</body </html>'
    return HttpResponse(txts)
```

На выходе по index получаем:

```txt
2 дня, 2 часа ago
5 дней, 1 час ago
9 hours ago
4 дня, 9 часов ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
1 день, 9 часов ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
3 дня ago
4 дня, 1 час ago
1 неделя, 1 день ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
3 дня, 5 часов ago
5 дней, 5 часов ago
4 дня ago
1 неделя, 1 день ago
3 дня, 1 час ago
3 дня, 3 часа ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
5 дней ago
3 дня, 6 часов ago
2 дня, 5 часов ago
5 дней, 6 часов ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
1 неделя ago
3 дня, 4 часа ago
2 дня, 2 часа ago
2 дня, 1 час ago
1 неделя ago
2 дня, 6 часов ago
1 неделя, 1 день ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
1 день, 3 часа ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
4 дня, 8 часов ago
1 неделя ago
4 hours ago
6 hours ago
4 дня, 9 часов ago
2 дня, 7 часов ago
5 дней, 7 часов ago
4 дня ago
5 дней, 3 часа ago
1 неделя ago
1 неделя ago
an hour ago
5 дней, 3 часа ago
1 неделя, 1 день ago
2 дня, 1 час ago
1 неделя, 1 день ago
2 дня, 3 часа ago
2 дня, 8 часов ago
7 hours ago
1 неделя ago
1 неделя ago
1 неделя ago
5 дней, 4 часа ago
4 hours ago
3 hours ago
1 день, 5 часов ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
6 дней ago
1 неделя ago
1 неделя, 2 дня ago
```

То есть не смотря на включенный русский язык не все фразы выглядят русскими.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим, и если да, то как победили?

Comment: А у вас 'django.contrib.humanize' добавлено в  INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @strawdog не, не было установлено. И это решило проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать набор фильтров `django.contrib.humanize`, необходимо их зарегистрировать, то есть, добавить в раздел `INSTALLED_APPS` файла `settings.py`.